# how to use sed to replace the Nth line with the Mth line in the same file by line numbers

Tags: sed, replace, line

Here is my problem:

- Given a text file.
- The data in each line isn't known.
- Need to replace line 3 with line 5.
- The line number to be replaced, and the line number to replace with, are given and are constant.
- The line numbers are never the first line, or the last line.
- The number of lines in the file doesn't change

Before running the code

```
A34JC
P1@%NWA]
MM1              //Line to be replaced
M@K(FD
BWKD             //Line to replace with
Z
```

After running the code

```
A34JC
P1@%NWA]
BWKD             //Data in Line 3 was replaced with the data from line 5
M@K(FD
BWKD
Z
```

I really don't mind using shell, sed (or awk though I am not familiar with it). From what I saw here I tried the following

```
sed 3s/.*/???/ file1.txt > file2.txt
```

I'm embarrassed to say what I have tried at the `???`. I know I can manually insert a text there, but the problem is I don't know what data line 5 holds.

I also tried various replacements ways, but that was even worse.

```
sed 3d;5r file1.txt file1.txt > file2
```

in short, I am clueless.

### Updates

Potong's first solution didn't work for me, but the alternative work. I now have a continuation question.

So the situation is this - I am having to repeat a very annoying process all the time. Without getting into it to much:

- I am running Windows.
- I have a text file containing processes Id numbers, and under each of the numbers are the settings that belong to the specific process.
- The process ID changes every time I restart the process.
- The process new ID automatically writes into the txt file.
- Instead of setting the process setting from scratch, I simply copy the new random generated Process ID number, and erase the data of the settings that are just junk now.
- There are 4 such process running at the same time. So they always add and change together.

Here is what I figured so far:

Note: I have added -i as to save the changes done of the same file

```
.\sed -E -i '28{:a;N;60!ba;s/[^\n]*(.*\n(.*))/\2\1/}' config.txt
.\sed -E -i '36{:a;N;64!ba;s/[^\n]*(.*\n(.*))/\2\1/}' config.txt
.\sed -E -i '44{:a;N;68!ba;s/[^\n]*(.*\n(.*))/\2\1/}' config.txt
.\sed -E -i '52{:a;N;72!ba;s/[^\n]*(.*\n(.*))/\2\1/}' config.txt
```

You can see 28,36,44,52 and 60,64,68,72 are series.

Here is what I need more help with:

I want to run all 4 of these commands automatically, For instance as .bat file or something similar. Can it work using .bat file?

I know cmd requires me to remove the ' from the command, and may add line instead of overwrite. It works pretty well in power shell but show do I make a .bat file to run on power shell?

I want to add a command at the end to delete everything from line 60 and onward. How do I do that?

Comment: Use the editor to markup the code and data properly (`{}` key or prepend with 4 spaces), as it is now, it's quite confusing to read. Also, post some sample data with the expected output.

Comment: Thank you. Apologies, This is my first message here and I wasn't sure at all how to use the forum or codes...
I did feel I posted sample data with expected output, did I not?
Someone fixed it for me. so thank you, I will try better next post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '3{e sed -n "5p" file' -e 'd}' file
```

Evaluates sed within sed using the `e` command.

Alternative:

```
sed -E '3{:a;N;5!ba;s/[^\n]*(.*\n(.*))/\2\1/}' file
```

Comment: Hi potong! Thanky ou very much! The first option didn't work for me. 
Your alternative do work but I have a few things I would like to see if you can help me with please.
Can you check the update to my question? at the top? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the given example, you can use this:

```
sed '3d;4{h;d};5{p;x;p;x}' file1.txt >file2.txt
```

- `3d`: delete line 3
- `4{h;d}`: copy line 4 to hold space; delete line 4 (for now)
- `5{p;x;p;x}`: print line 5 (becomes output line 3); exchange hold and pattern space; print the previously held line 4; re-exchange hold and pattern space for automatic printing of line 5

If there's more than one line between the to-be-replaced and the replacement line, e. g. 3 and 7, respectively, we'd need an additional command to append the lines in between:

```
sed '3d;4{h;d};5,6{H;d};7{p;x;p;x}' file1.txt >file2.txt
```

Comment: Thank you but as I will update here now I need to switch more then 1 line and the lines has more then 1 space between them